# modifying 3rd party django projects

Tags: django, git, github

I'm to the point where I use many 3rd party apps, but I need to extend them. I'm trying to figure out the best way to modify an existing app. In the past I have just modified the code in the site-packages (knowing that it was bad), but that has its obvious downfalls.

Right now the closest I can get is to fork the github repo, and then I create an app in my project that I hook up to the forked github repo.

The problem is that what I'm forking is the project and not the app. So that means I have a structure like: project/app-project/app after I fork. Other things are also in the app-project directory such as LICENSE, AUTHORS etc.

```
Project
--App1
----Code
--App2
----Code
--ForkedAppProject
----LICENCE
----AUTHORS
----ForkedApp
------Code
```

If I just take the code inside the App directory, I can modify that, but then I'm losing all the source control for the Project (LICENSE, AUTHORS, etc) and that kind of defeats the purpose of forking the open-source app.

I want to set it up so that I am modifying the app code, but I am modifying so that my changes could contribute to the open-source project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary to place forked app inside your project. After forking and modifying you can add `ForkedApp` folder to `PYTHONPATH` or build your own package like this

```
python setup.py sdist
```

Then install it in your system/virtualenv and update `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. I should have asked this a long time ago.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and most convenient way to do this is to use pip `--editable` option. See [“Editable” Installs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#editable-installs) in pip documentation.